# How to extract the player's information from the Statistics page as per the HTML?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape some information for a website using selenium below is the link to the website http://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/playerProfile?playerId=4742
the information i am trying to get is under the player 'statistics' my code right now opens the player's profile and then opens the player's statistics page i am trying to find a way to extract the information in the player's statistics page below is my code so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/playerProfile?playerId=4742")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
try:
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="playerPills"]/li[9]/a')
dropdown.click()


bm = driver.find_element_by_id('statisticsPill')
bm.click()

for i in soup.select('#statistics table.table tr'):
    print(i)
    data1 = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in i.select("th,td")]
    print(data1)

except ValueError:
      print("error")
```

I    
                
                    
                        
                            
                            
                                Serve

```
                            <th class="pct-data text-right"><i class="fa fa-percent"></i></th>
                            <th class="raw-data text-right" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ace %</td>



                            <th class="text-right pct-data">23.4%</th>
                            <th class="raw-data text-right" style="display: none;">12942 / 55377</th>


                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Double Fault %</td>



                            <th class="text-right pct-data">4.2%</th>
                            <th class="raw-data text-right" style="display:
```

Comment: `to extract the information` which information?

Comment: @DebanjanB sorry i have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the information of the player's from the **Statistics** page you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/playerProfile?playerId=4742")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='playerPills']//a[@class='dropdown-toggle'][normalize-space()='Statistics']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']//a[@id='statisticsPill'][normalize-space()='Statistics']"))).click()
  statistics_items = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-condensed table-hover table-striped']//tbody//tr/td")))
  statistics_value = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-condensed table-hover table-striped']//tbody//tr//following::th[1]")))
  for item, value in zip(statistics_items, statistics_value):
      print('{} {}'.format(item.text, value.text))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Ace % 4.0%
  Double Fault % 2.1%
  1st Serve % 68.7%
  1st Serve Won % 71.8%
  2nd Serve Won % 57.3%
  Break Points Saved % 66.3%
  Service Points Won % 67.2%
  Service Games Won % 85.6%
  Ace Against % Return
  Double Fault Against % 7.2%
  1st Srv. Return Won % 3.4%
  2nd Srv. Return Won % 34.2%
  Break Points Won % 55.3%
  Return Points Won % 44.9%
  Return Games Won % 42.4%
  Points Dominance 33.3%
  Games Dominance Total
  Break Points Ratio 1.29
  Total Points Won % 2.31
  Games Won % 1.33
  Sets Won % 54.4%
  Matches Won % 59.7%
  Match Time 77.2%
  ```

Comment: thanks for you help that seems to work can you recommend any place where i can learn more about selenium?

Comment: @smith Select any Selenium tutorial related website and get your hands dirty with code. Feel free to raise a question whenever you are in doubt. Try to get to the core of each and everything you come across. You will be a expert soon !!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the location of this line -

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
```

It should come AFTER you have clicked on the "Statistics" tab. Because then only the table loads and soup can parse it.

Final code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'//path/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/playerProfile?playerId=4742")

try:
   dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="playerPills"]/li[9]/a')
   dropdown.click()
   bm = driver.find_element_by_id('statisticsPill')
   bm.click()
   driver.maximize_window()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
   for i in soup.select('#statisticsOverview table tr'):
     print(i.text)
     data1 = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in i.select("th,td")]
     print(data1)

except ValueError:
      print("error")
```

Comment: i notice if you do not maximize the window your code will not work why is that just curious?